# Using the ArcGIS Time Slider on non-temporal data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatio-temporal-data

We're looking at re-purposing ArcGIS temporal tools, chiefly the [Time Slider](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/time/using-the-time-slider.htm), to model potential flood hazards. Our input data are a series of polygons showing varying water depth. Elevation (depth) is stored as metres in an attribute field as well as PolygonZ. The field value range is small, e.g. `316.0` to `320.8`.

On of the immediate issues we encounter is that the tools require data to be in YYYY/YYYYMM/.../YYYYMMDDhhmmss format and truncate decimals. It would be nice to be able to leverage the automatic labelling too, but that's not essential.

So, how would you restructure the input data to make maximal use of the temporal tools? The primary result will be used in ArcGIS Desktop, but there is talk of publishing on ArcGIS Online as well. So try to accommodate both avenues if feasible.

[image: input poly features, various extents]

[image: time tools truncate decimals]

Answer (score 1):

#### Pretend Depth are Years

Convert metres to centimetres, then to Date using [ConvertTimeField](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/convert-time-field.htm). So `316.0`, `318.4` becomes `3160-01-01`, `3184-01-01`.

For ArcMap Time Slider "show cumulatively" must be checked, else the "years" with no data draw a blank screen. This also means there will be some stages in the animation/slider where nothing appears to happen. Depending on the size of the gaps this could be a minor or major problem.

In the map change "Time Slider toolbar >> Options >> Time Display" format to `YYYY` and then [Appearance] >> Text to 
`Water height: <dyn type="dataFrame" property="time" emptyStr=""/> cm`

[image: Time Slider options]

**Result:**

[image: GIS animation screen capture]

#### What didn't work:

*Enable time on Elevation field (values: 316.6, 318.4, …)*

The format is expected to be YYYY, YYYYMM, …etc. Decimals are truncated. Time slider has no effect on the displayed polygons.

*Convert Elevation meters to centimeters (values: 31660, 31840, …)*

Added new field, calculated to equal `Elevation_m * 100`. Set the time properties to go by year (YYYY). Everything appeared happy, but when the Time Slider toolbar was turned on no polygons at all were drawn. Advancing the slider back and forth and using [play] had no effect.